# Live boot error - ASPM could not configure common clock

Tags: boot, live-usb

I have followed the procedure in https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0
to create a bootable USB with ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso.   The USB boots fine on an old Dell PC but when I boot from it on an old Asus P6T based gaming machine that has Windows 7 and Windows 10 installed I get this error message (and no others) during the boot sequence, and the sequence then hangs.

[   1.355109] pci 0000:07:00.0: ASPM: Could not configure common clock

I have done an internet search for this message but found very little.  What there is suggests the issue may have to do with having a PCIe NVIDIA graphics card (GeForce GTX 460) installed or VT-d enabled.  However, I have updated to the latest Nvidia driver and checked the VT-d setting in BIOS (it was already disabled), to no avail.   I have also checked the Windows logs for any kind of PCI/PCIe issue but found nothing.

Can anyone suggest what to look at next?

Comment: I suggest booting with `nomodeset`.

Comment: Many thanks GabrielaGarcia.  I tried this option (booted from live USB, waited for Ubuntu keyboard icon, clicked a key to open the menu, hit F6 for more options, selected nomodeset, then continued.  The same ASPM error message popped up again, but this time the boot sequence did not hang and I was able to complete the installation.  Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. The next step is to install the Nvidia drivers (open Additional Drivers and select the recommended/tested version. You may need to boot with the `nomodeset` again.